# Memory leak with hashMap

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak problem that I need to resolve it.
I have this File can help me to find the memory leak

```
2'777'369'064 (62.72%) [32] 8 class */planning/canvas/shared/serializable/ActionCycleSZ 0x68759f768
|- 2'777'365'536 (62.72%) [256] 35 org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader 0x688ce9df8
|  |- 2'775'589'272 (62.68%) [48] 1 java/util/HashMap 0x688ceabe0
|  |  |- 2'775'589'224 (62.68%) [32'784] 3'533 array of java/util/HashMap$Entry 0x689af74c0
|  |     |- 2'763'509'944 (62.41%) [24] 2 java/util/HashMap$Entry 0x68a0b1f98
|  |     |  |- 2'763'509'744 (62.41%) [40] 1 org/apache/catalina/loader/ResourceEntry 0x68a0b1fb0
|  |     |  |  |- 2'763'509'704 (62.41%) [32] 41 class */gwt/server/servlet/TaProjectsSessionManager 0x68653c8e8
|  |     |  |     |- 2'763'047'360 (62.4%) [32] 6 class */selfservice/SelfConfigurator 0x6875922a0
|  |     |  |     |  |- 2'763'047'328 (62.4%) [16] 2 */gwt/server/servlet/TaProjectsSessionManager$1 0x689aee328
|  |     |  |     |  |  |- 2'154'573'968 (48.66%) [160] 30 */impl/HRSessionImpl 0x689ee49f8
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |- 2'138'350'824 (48.29%) [32] 3 java/util/Collections$SynchronizedMap 0x689ee4c70
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |  |- 2'138'350'760 (48.29%) [64] 3 org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap 0x689ee5218
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |  |  |- 2'134'913'368 (48.21%) [32] 2 org/apache/commons/collections/map/AbstractLinkedMap$LinkEntry 0x68a3573d0
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |  |  |- 3'437'328 (0.08%) [2'064] 121 array of org/apache/commons/collections/map/AbstractHashedMap$HashEntry 0x68a356bc8
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |  |  |- 16 (0%) [16] 1 org/apache/commons/collections/map/AbstractHashedMap$KeySet 0x69d443088
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |  |- 32 (0%) [16] 2 java/util/Collections$SynchronizedSet 0x69d443098
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |  |- 2'138'350'824 (48.29%) [32] 3 java/util/Collections$SynchronizedMap 0x689ee4c70
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |- 16'078'096 (0.36%) [104] 19 */impl/Dictionary 0x689ee4ad8
```

I conclude that the class ActionCycleSZ produce the memory leak
this is ActionCycleSZ

```
public class ActionCycleSZ extends ActionDTO implements IsSerializable {
private CycleSZ bean;

public ActionCycleSZ() {
}

public ActionCycleSZ(Type actionType, CycleSZ bean ) {
    super(actionType);
    this.bean = bean;
}

public CycleSZ getBean(){
    return bean;
}
public void setBean(CycleSZ bean){
    this.bean = bean;
 }
}





public class CycleSZ implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
String cycleLabel;
Date startDate;
Date endDate;
String startDateDTO;
String endDateDTO;
Integer numlign;
String accumulatedHours;
List<SiteSZ> listOfSites = new LinkedList<SiteSZ>();
//getter and setter 
}


public class SiteSZ implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int week;
String siteLabel;
Date startDate;
Date endDate;
String startHour;
String endHour;
String site;
String time;
String particularSlotTime;
Integer numlign;
DaySZ dayAttribute;
String accumulatedWeekHours;
Map<Util.WeekDays,DaySZ> mapAttributes = new 
LinkedHashMap<Util.WeekDays,DaySZ>();
boolean workedDay; //Flag for Exceptional Canevas Entry
boolean reposHebdo;
String contratId; //contratId for Exceptional Canevas Entry
```

In all ActionCycleSZ I have just this Map Map mapAttributes = new 
LinkedHashMap();
I think that is the problem of the leak. Do I think right?
 I see the code and I don't see something like a memory leak.
Can anyone help me how to detect this memory leak or give me examples of memory leak due to hashmap

Comment: Why do you think this is a memory leak and not a lot of data, for example, cached somewhere?

Comment: this memory leak happens when the client uses the application, he has a lot of data. but it is a memory leak I use IBM  headAnalyser to detect it

Comment: If he has a lot of data, and all that data should be stored on heap, this is not a memory leak, this is design flow. If he had only small amount of data, and it stayed on heap and duped itself indefinitely, then sure.